# Executing a bash script from Electron app

Tags: javascript, html, bash, electron

I am trying to execute bash script within Electron index.html button click. Here's my code which index.html calling renderer.js, and renderer.js opens the bash script. When I run the code, I see a button that I can click, but even when I click it, I do not see "Hello World" from stdout terminal. Does anyone have any advice for solving this problem? Any help much appreciated!

**index.html**

```
 <h0>My-Flection</h0>
 <button id="openBtn">Open</button>
 <script>
   require('./renderer.js')
 </script>
```

**renderer.js**

```
const openBtn = document.getElementById('openBtn')
const shell = require('electron').shell

openBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    shell.openItem("./test.sh")
})
```

**test.sh**

```
echo "Hello World"
```

Comment: Is this test.sh file in same location?

Comment: @KishanVaishnani It has to be or otherwise they wouldn't put "./test.sh" but I could be wrong.

Comment: @KishanVaishnani yes, they're all in the same directory.

Answer (score 7):

Electron's [`shell`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/shell) method is not really used for running scripts.
It's used for showing a file in the systems file manager, opening a file "in the desktop's default manner", moving files
to trash / recycle bin and playing a beep sound among other things.

As you are using Electron you should really take advantage of the different processes and run your script(s)
within the main process. Doing so will prevent any possible locking of your render process (plus separate your concerns
if you are
so inclined).

Below is a `preload.js` script that allows communication between your main process and render process(es) via the use of
whitelisted channel names. The only implementations within this `preload.js` script is the use of [`ipcRenderer`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer). See [Context Isolation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/context-isolation) and [Inter-Process Communication](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc) for more information

---

In this `preload.js` script we are using the channel name `runScript` to communicate from the render process to the
main process.

`preload.js` (main process)

```js
// Import the necessary Electron components.
const contextBridge = require('electron').contextBridge;
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

// White-listed channels.
const ipc = {
    'render': {
        // From render to main.
        'send': [
            'runScript' // Channel name
        ],
        // From main to render.
        'receive': [],
        // From render to main and back again.
        'sendReceive': []
    }
};

// Exposed protected methods in the render process.
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    // Allowed 'ipcRenderer' methods.
    'ipcRender', {
        // From render to main.
        send: (channel, args) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.send;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                ipcRenderer.send(channel, args);
            }
        },
        // From main to render.
        receive: (channel, listener) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.receive;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                // Deliberately strip event as it includes `sender`.
                ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => listener(...args));
            }
        },
        // From render to main and back again.
        invoke: (channel, args) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.sendReceive;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                return ipcRenderer.invoke(channel, args);
            }
        }
    }
);
```

This `preload.js` script is used like so...

```js
/**
 * Render --> Main
 * ---------------
 * Render:  window.ipcRender.send('channel', data); // Data is optional.
 * Main:    electronIpcMain.on('channel', (event, data) => { methodName(data); })
 *
 * Main --> Render
 * ---------------
 * Main:    windowName.webContents.send('channel', data); // Data is optional.
 * Render:  window.ipcRender.receive('channel', (data) => { methodName(data); });
 *
 * Render --> Main (Value) --> Render
 * ----------------------------------
 * Render:  window.ipcRender.invoke('channel', data).then((result) => { methodName(result); });
 * Main:    electronIpcMain.handle('channel', (event, data) => { return someMethod(data); });
 *
 * Render --> Main (Promise) --> Render
 * ------------------------------------
 * Render:  window.ipcRender.invoke('channel', data).then((result) => { methodName(result); });
 * Main:    electronIpcMain.handle('channel', async (event, data) => {
 *              return await promiseName(data)
 *                  .then(() => { return result; })
 *          });
 */
```

---

In this `main.js` script, listen for a message on channel name `runScript`, then run the script
using [`spawn`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/child_process.html#child_processspawncommand-args-options).

> [`exec`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/child_process.html#child_processexeccommand-options-callback) could
> be used if streaming is **not** needed. IE: `exec` buffers output.

`main.js` (main process)

```js
'use strict';

const electronApp = require('electron').app;
const electronBrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow;
const electronIpcMain = require('electron').ipcMain;

const nodePath = require("path");
const nodeChildProcess = require('child_process');

let window;

function createWindow() {
    const window = new electronBrowserWindow({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        show: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false,
            contextIsolation: true,
            preload: nodePath.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    });

    window.loadFile('index.html')
        .then(() => { window.show(); });

    return window;
}

electronApp.on('ready', () => {
    window = createWindow();
});

electronApp.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        electronApp.quit();
    }
});

electronApp.on('activate', () => {
    if (electronBrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createWindow();
    }
});

// ---

electronIpcMain.on('runScript', () => {
    // Windows
    let script = nodeChildProcess.spawn('cmd.exe', ['/c', 'test.bat', 'arg1', 'arg2']);

    // MacOS & Linux
    // let script = nodeChildProcess.spawn('bash', ['test.sh', 'arg1', 'arg2']);

    console.log('PID: ' + script.pid);

    script.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log('stdout: ' + data);
    });

    script.stderr.on('data', (err) => {
        console.log('stderr: ' + err);
    });

    script.on('exit', (code) => {
        console.log('Exit Code: ' + code);
    });
})
```

---

Some test scripts.

`test.bat` (for Windows)

```batch
echo "hello World"

echo %1%
echo %2%
```

`test.sh` (for MacOS & Linux)

```sh
echo "Hello World"

echo $1
echo $2
```

---

Lastly, here is a simplified `index.html` file. On `button` `click`, `send` a message to the main process via the
channel
name `runScript`.

`index.html` (render process)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Electron Test</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="button" id="button" value="Run Script">
    </body>

    <script>
        document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
            window.ipcRender.send('runScript');
        })
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

electron + bash. demo.

A slightly less simple electron app that execs a bash function when you click a button

https://github.com/patarleth/bashit-electron

---

#/mydir/bash_src/main.js

```
const {app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain} = require('electron')
const child_process = require('child_process').execFile;

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let win

function createWindow () {
    // Create the browser window.
    win = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})
    
    // and load the index.html of the app.
    win.loadFile('index.html')
    
    // Open the DevTools.
    // win.webContents.openDevTools()
    
    // Emitted when the window is closed.
    win.on('closed', () => {
        // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
        // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
        // when you should delete the corresponding element.
        win = null
    })
}

function bashit_fn(sender, fnName) {
    var executablePath = '/usr/bin/env'
    var source_path = 'source ' + __dirname + '/bash_src/lib.sh; ' + fnName;
    var parameters = [ 'bash', '-c', source_path ];
    
    child_process(executablePath, parameters, function(err, data) {
        var msg = data.toString();
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            msg += err;
        }
        var eventName = 'bash-function-' + fnName;
        sender.send(eventName, msg);
        console.log(msg);
    });
}

function hello_fn(sender) {
    bashit_fn(sender, 'hello_fn');
}

ipcMain.on('call-bash-function-hello_fn', (event, arg) => {
    hello_fn(event.sender);
})

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow)

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    app.quit()
})

app.on('activate', () => {
    // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
    // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
    if (win === null) {
        createWindow()
    }
})

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.
```

---

#/mydir/bash_src/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>bash exec functions!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>bash exec function examples!</h1>

    <button id="hello-button">test bash function</button>
    
    <h2 id="hello-header">...</h2>

    <script>
      var ipc = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
      
      var helloButton = document.getElementById('hello-button');

      // when you click the button it sends an event named 'hello-from-renderer' to the backend process
      helloButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
        ipc.send('call-bash-function-hello_fn', 'hello');
        console.log('hello-button clicked');
      });

      // iff the backend sends an event named 'bash-function-hello_fn' the h2 header named 'hello-header' html is updated
      ipc.on('bash-function-hello_fn',(event,dataFromMain) => {
        console.log( 'bash-function-hello_fn |' + dataFromMain + '|');
        var helloH2 = document.getElementById('hello-header');
        helloH2.innerHTML = dataFromMain;
      });
     </script
  </body>
</html>
```

#/mydir/bash_src/lib.sh

```
LIB_SCRIPT_DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" >/dev/null && pwd )"

hello_fn() {
    echo "hello from hello_fn $(pwd) - LIB_SCRIPT_DIR $LIB_SCRIPT_DIR"
}
```

---

[image]

[image]